# Is there anyway to remove anything from the request object you get in express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Most express middleware look like this:

```
var foo = function( req, res, next ) {

}
```

Is there anyway to REMOVE properties from the req object such that it will reflected in the next handler in the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `delete` it.

For example:

```
function logout (req, res, next){
    delete req.session['user'];
    res.redirect(302,'/');
};
```

Obviously if you are deleting things subsequent middleware expects to be present you may have issues.

You can read the doc on delete [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: Have you actually tested this with an express.js middleware?

Comment: Interesting that you can't delete req, but you can delete it's properties. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your question - I pulled the above out of an app, so "yes." Regarding your comment, I'm not even sure what it would mean to delete `req` - it's a parameter to the function. What would be deleted?

Comment: It's a parameter of the function yes but it's also a reference to an object that is shared by all middleware. I thought I could strip out some properties from it before it's exposed to my user but that's starting to look pretty messy.

Comment: That might be messy, but I also may not understand why or how exactly the request object would be exposed to the user. Without understanding your specific needs, my guess is you might be better off making a copy (deep or shallow) of selected properties of the request and pass that copy along.